# How do I set Android app as device owner?

Tags: android, device-owner, android-enterprise

I'm developing Kiosk Mode App for my organization.

The only thing I want is to set my App as device-owner-mode to launch the app in Kiosk Mode.
I am debugging this by using adb shell to set this app as device owner.
The problem is how I set this as device owner on the other device without using adb???

I found some ways by scanning QR code Provisioning.. but this method is really confusing..
Should I develop EMM Console kind of thing to do this..?

As I said the only thind I want is just set the app as device owner. No need for managing that device or create multi profile.

How can I do this?? Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set your app as device owner via [QR code provisioning](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#qr_code_method) you need to:

- host your APK on a public URL
- generate a QR code containing your APK URL and checksum, along with your package name and admin receiver name (cf [example](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#example_qr_code_bundle))
- factory-reset your device
- tap 6 times on the initial setup screen
- scan your QR code